# How do I create Perl module templates for more than one module in the same namespace?

Tags: perl

I use [`h2xs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/h2xs.html) and [Module::Starter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Starter) to create templates for my Perl modules. All these and others like Module::Build are great for creating one-off modules. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out a "clean" way of creating a family of related modules and their documentation and test suite templates in one go.

Specfically, is it possible to create A::P, A::Q, A::R ... in a single invocation of `h2xs` or other starter tools, or even add A::Q, A::R once a template for A::P has been created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`module-starter` can be invoked thus, to create all the modules in a single invocation:

```
module-starter --author='Example Author' --email=author@example.com --module=A::P --module=A::Q --module=A::R --distro='My-A-Module-Distro'
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do nicely. Any ideas how this couldbe done with h2xs?

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I do not know how to achieve the same with `h2xs`.